# Disable systemd-random-seed

Tags: boot, systemd, services

I am looking to speed up the boot time on my Raspberry pi and `systemd-random-seed` is taking 20s (old Pi 1). From what I've read up this is waiting to collect entropy to generate a system random seed. I don't care whatsoever about security and I'm wondering if there is some way to hard-code this, disable it, or otherwise make it not take so ridiculously long to boot?

I tried just running `systemctl disable systemd-random-seed` to see what would happen and it still ran at boot, so evidently it's being started by another service or something.

I also tried adding `random.trust_cpu=on` to cmdline.txt based on something I read, but it seems to have done nothing.

I'm completely new to Linux and raspberry if that wasn't already obvious, so sorry if it's a dumb question a requires a dumb answer... I attempted to look through the man page and it's completely over my head (wasn't sure how to translate that into the boot process).

Comment: On what are you basing this conclusion? systemd services start asynchronously, so even if you think something is causing "slow" boot (which 20s isn't - my Pi4 takes 30sec) removing it is unlikely to make a significant difference.

Comment: Incidentally WHY are you rebooting - I only reboot if updating firmware, other that that my Pi run 24/7?

Comment: @Milliways I ran `systemd-analyze plot` and this service was by far the slowest. So far as I know that is the best way to time boot services... As to WHY, I am working on a camera controller and I want it to boot as quickly as possible because this is a set-up I will be carrying on film sets (not sitting at home or in a server room or something).

Comment: @Milliways This guy got his boot time down to 3-4 seconds ;) http://himeshp.blogspot.com/2018/08/fast-boot-with-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 0):

Many over the years have tried to minimise boot times, and it can be done.

The best start is `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Optimising anything not on the critical-chain won't help. Disabling networking is often successful.

Comment: So this means that it isn't taking any time? Why is it that when I run this the critical chain starts @31.6s - is there nothing I can do about the time before second 31?

Comment: Also, and I do realize this is a bit off topic, can I disable `systemd-timesyncd`? According to my critical chain it is taking 2.3s and I don't particularly care about time...

Comment: Everything takes time, but most run asynchronously. This is obviously limited on a single CPU system.`systemd-timesyncd` synchronises the clock. It is not needed, and will do nothing unless you have a network and you will still have clock - it just won't show the real time. `systemd-analyze time` shows kernel & userspace time.

Comment: Ok so just to wrap this up because it isn't totally clear to me yet, it was totally false to think that `systemd-random-seed` was slowing my boot times? I tried `systemd-analyze time` and yes it shows 4s for kernel and 30s for userspace but that doesn't really help me much except to tell me that userspace is where I need to focus. But what is taking so long in userspace, that isn't in the critical chain? (which only showed about 5 seconds worth of time)

Comment: I suggest you read `man systemd-analyze` and look at `blame`. This is complex, and I don't understand all of it. I am afraid I can't offer any concrete help for your specific problem, other than disabling everything you don't need.

Comment: Ok well thanks for the help anyway! Regardless of my fumbling I did get my boot time cut almost in half since installing fresh Raspberry pi OS (about 1min to about 33s). Still want to figure out this seed random thing though, I don't think that's fully clarified yet.